# Spark Yarn Tuning Settings

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am experiencing very strange thing with respect to running of a spark code snippet on standalone spark and Spark running on a cluster with YARN.

Here is the code I tried. Just a small function converting the text field to word2vec vectors. My data looks like below:

```
[Row(id=u'-33753621', title=u'Royal Bank of Scotland is testing a robot that could solve your banking problems (RBS)', text_cleaned=u"If you hate dealing with bank tellers or customer service representatives, then the Royal Bank of Scotland might have a solution for you.If this program is successful, it could be a big step forward on the road to automated customer service through the use of AI, notes Laurie Beaver, research associate for BI Intelligence, Business Insider's premium research service.It's noteworthy that Luvo does not operate via a third-party app such as Facebook Messenger, WeChat, or Kik, all of which are currently trying to create bots that would assist in customer service within their respective platforms.Luvo would be available through the web and through smartphones. It would also use machine learning to learn from its mistakes, which should ultimately help with its response accuracy.Down the road, Luvo would become a supplement to the human staff. It can currently answer 20 set questions but as that number grows, it would allow the human employees to more complicated issues. If a problem is beyond Luvo's comprehension, then it would refer the customer to a bank employee; however,\xa0a user could choose to speak with a human instead of Luvo anyway.AI such as Luvo, if successful, could help businesses become more efficient and increase their productivity, while simultaneously improving customer service capacity, which would consequently\xa0save money that would otherwise go toward manpower.And this trend is already starting. Google, Microsoft, and IBM are investing significantly into AI research. Furthermore, the global AI market is estimated to grow from approximately $420 million in 2014 to $5.05 billion in 2020, according to a forecast by Research and Markets.\xa0The move toward AI would be just one more way in which the digital age is disrupting retail banking. Customers, particularly millennials, are increasingly moving toward digital banking, and as a result, they're walking into their banks' traditional brick-and-mortar branches less often than ever before."),
```

Code snippet I have:

```
def word2Vec(df):
    """ This function takes in the data frame of the texts and finds the Word vector 
    representation of that

    """


    from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, Word2Vec


    # Carrying out the Tokenization of the text documents (splitting into words)

    tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="text_cleaned", outputCol="tokenised_text")
    tokensDf = tokenizer.transform(df)

    # Implementing the word2Vec model

    word2Vec = Word2Vec(vectorSize=300, seed=42, inputCol="tokenised_text", outputCol="w2v_vector")
    w2vmodel = word2Vec.fit(tokensDf)
    w2vdf=w2vmodel.transform(tokensDf)


    return w2vdf,w2vmodel

w2vdf,w2vmodel=word2Vec(df_cleaned)
```

This above code snippet I tried first on Spark Standalone with following Spark configuration being set up in the beginning:

**Spark Local:**

```
sc.stop()

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf()

conf.setAppName('Learnfit_RSS')\
 .set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")\
 .set("spark.executor.cores",5)\
 .set("spark.executor.instances",10)\
 .set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",1024)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

This code ran totally fine and gave me the following output: If you see transformer in the above method has worked fine creating the corresponding columns.

```
[Row(id=u'-33753621', tokenised_text=[u'if', u'you', u'hate', u'dealing', u'with', u'bank', u'tellers', u'or', u'customer', u'service', u'representatives,', u'then', u'the', u'royal', u'bank', u'of', u'scotland', u'might', u'have', u'a', u'solution', u'for', u'you.if', u'this', u'program', u'is', u'successful,', u'it', u'could', u'be', u'a', u'big', u'step', u'forward', u'on', u'the', u'road', u'to', u'automated', u'customer', u'service', u'through', u'the', u'use', u'of', u'ai,', u'notes', u'laurie', u'beaver,', u'research', u'associate', u'for', u'bi', u'intelligence,', u'business', u"insider's", u'premium', u'research', u"service.it's", u'noteworthy', u'that', u'luvo', u'does', u'not', u'operate', u'via', u'a', u'third-party', u'app', u'such', u'as', u'facebook', u'messenger,', u'wechat,', u'or', u'kik,', u'all', u'of', u'which', u'are', u'currently', u'trying', u'to', u'create', u'bots', u'that', u'would', u'assist', u'in', u'customer', u'service', u'within', u'their', u'respective', u'platforms.luvo', u'would', u'be', u'available', u'through', u'the', u'web', u'and', u'through', u'smartphones.', u'it', u'would', u'also', u'use', u'machine', u'learning', u'to', u'learn', u'from', u'its', u'mistakes,', u'which', u'should', u'ultimately', u'help', u'with', u'its', u'response', u'accuracy.down', u'the', u'road,', u'luvo', u'would', u'become', u'a', u'supplement', u'to', u'the', u'human', u'staff.', u'it', u'can', u'currently', u'answer', u'20', u'set', u'questions', u'but', u'as', u'that', u'number', u'grows,', u'it', u'would', u'allow', u'the', u'human', u'employees', u'to', u'more', u'complicated', u'issues.', u'if', u'a', u'problem', u'is', u'beyond', u"luvo's", u'comprehension,', u'then', u'it', u'would', u'refer', u'the', u'customer', u'to', u'a', u'bank', u'employee;', u'however,\xa0a', u'user', u'could', u'choose', u'to', u'speak', u'with', u'a', u'human', u'instead', u'of', u'luvo', u'anyway.ai', u'such', u'as', u'luvo,', u'if', u'successful,', u'could', u'help', u'businesses', u'become', u'more', u'efficient', u'and', u'increase', u'their', u'productivity,', u'while', u'simultaneously', u'improving', u'customer', u'service', u'capacity,', u'which', u'would', u'consequently\xa0save', u'money', u'that', u'would', u'otherwise', u'go', u'toward', u'manpower.and', u'this', u'trend', u'is', u'already', u'starting.', u'google,', u'microsoft,', u'and', u'ibm', u'are', u'investing', u'significantly', u'into', u'ai', u'research.', u'furthermore,', u'the', u'global', u'ai', u'market', u'is', u'estimated', u'to', u'grow', u'from', u'approximately', u'$420', u'million', u'in', u'2014', u'to', u'$5.05', u'billion', u'in', u'2020,', u'according', u'to', u'a', u'forecast', u'by', u'research', u'and', u'markets.\xa0the', u'move', u'toward', u'ai', u'would', u'be', u'just', u'one', u'more', u'way', u'in', u'which', u'the', u'digital', u'age', u'is', u'disrupting', u'retail', u'banking.', u'customers,', u'particularly', u'millennials,', u'are', u'increasingly', u'moving', u'toward', u'digital', u'banking,', u'and', u'as', u'a', u'result,', u"they're", u'walking', u'into', u'their', u"banks'", u'traditional', u'brick-and-mortar', u'branches', u'less', u'often', u'than', u'ever', u'before.'], w2v_vector=DenseVector([-0.0394, -0.0388, 0.0368, -0.0455, 0.0602, -0.0734, 0.0515, -0.0064, -0.068, -0.0438, 0.0671, 0.007, -0.0227, -0.0393, -0.0254, -0.024, 0.0115, 0.0415, -0.0116, -0.0169, 0.0545, -0.0439, 0.0414, 0.0312, -0.028, -0.0085, 0.0234, -0.1321, -0.0364, 0.0921, 0.0208, 0.0156, 0.0071, 0.0186, -0.0455, -0.0634, 0.0379, 0.0148, 0.0401, -0.0395, 0.0334, 0.0026, -0.0748, -0.0242, -0.0373, 0.0602, -0.0341, -0.0181, 0.0723, 0.0012, -0.1177, 0.0319, 0.0322, -0.1054, -0.0011, -0.0415, -0.0161, -0.0472, -0.0785, -0.0219, -0.0311, 0.0296, -0.0149, 0.04, 0.0001, 0.0337, 0.0841, -0.0344, -0.0171, 0.0425, -0.0122, 0.0838, 0.034, 0.0054, 0.0171, 0.0209, 0.0286, -0.0227, -0.0147, 0.0532, -0.027, -0.0645, -0.0858, -0.1444, 0.0824, 0.0128, -0.0485, -0.0378, -0.0229, 0.0331, -0.0248, 0.0427, -0.0624, -0.0324, -0.0271, 0.0135, 0.0504, 0.0028, -0.0772, 0.0121, -0.09, 0.031, -0.0771, -0.0703, 0.0947, 0.0997, -0.0084, 0.0774, 0.0281, 0.0405, -0.0475, 0.0217, 0.0591, 0.0241, -0.0287, 0.1064, 0.059, -0.06, 0.0422, 0.0908, 0.0341, 0.028, -0.0334, 0.0065, -0.0289, -0.0851, -0.0208, 0.0598, -0.0218, 0.001, 0.0049, 0.0257, 0.0076, -0.0599, 0.006, -0.0494, -0.0081, 0.0066, 0.0131, -0.0299, 0.0159, -0.0383, 0.0402, -0.0571, 0.0359, 0.0009, 0.0404, -0.0207, 0.0044, -0.0089, 0.0306, -0.0405, -0.0012, 0.0159, -0.005, -0.031, -0.0016, -0.0081, 0.0123, -0.0364, 0.0161, -0.0383, -0.0303, -0.0073, -0.0184, 0.0399, 0.0412, 0.0278, 0.0455, -0.0304, 0.0145, -0.0163, 0.0631, -0.0423, 0.0239, 0.0801, -0.0659, -0.0382, 0.0138, 0.051, 0.0056, -0.1605, 0.0018, 0.0077, -0.0076, 0.0119, 0.0397, -0.0823, -0.0462, 0.0465, 0.0735, 0.0283, -0.0205, -0.012, 0.0662, 0.0429, 0.0089, -0.0562, 0.1624, 0.0192, 0.0098, -0.0483, 0.0248, 0.0005, -0.0619, -0.0115, 0.0424, -0.0875, 0.0383, -0.0463, -0.0044, -0.0218, 0.014, -0.0404, -0.0198, -0.0162, -0.018, -0.0377, -0.0291, -0.0273, -0.0713, -0.0047, 0.0263, 0.0809, -0.0477, 0.0056, -0.0563, -0.061, -0.0185, 0.0223, -0.0718, 0.0163, 0.0061, -0.0716, -0.0081, 0.0079, 0.0156, -0.0124, -0.0223, -0.0092, -0.0621, 0.0033, 0.031, 0.0509, -0.0548, -0.0121, -0.0276, 0.0176, -0.04, 0.0382, -0.0737, 0.0202, -0.0314, -0.0702, 0.0685, -0.0928, 0.0698, -0.0484, 0.0541, -0.0539, 0.0895, 0.0076, -0.0134, -0.0116, 0.0227, -0.0361, -0.0729, -0.0068, -0.0501, 0.0137, -0.0134, 0.0039, -0.0463, 0.0289, -0.0336, -0.0731, -0.0362, -0.0195, 0.0466, -0.0132, 0.0336, 0.0108, 0.0219, -0.0702, -0.0117, -0.0285, 0.0644, -0.0806, 0.002, -0.0603, 0.0365, 0.0333, 0.0197, -0.037, 0.0983, 0.0011, 0.0436, 0.0506, -0.0089, -0.0134]))]
```

**For Spark on YARN:**

Now I ran the same above method on Spark Running on a cluster with YARN. I used the following configuration setting this time to boost performance and speed.

```
sc.stop()

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
conf = SparkConf()

conf.setAppName('Learnfit_RSS')\
 .set("spark.executor.memory", "30g")\
 .set("spark.executor.cores",5)\
 .set("spark.executor.instances",8)\
 .set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead",1024)

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

This is always giving me this OutOfMemory Error for Java Heap space no matter what I put in the above configuration.

```
2017-02-09 04:44:54,776 INFO  org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(58)) - Starting task 33.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 35, 107-02-c02.sc1.altiscale.com, partition 33,PROCESS_LOCAL, 2627307 bytes)
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:178)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task$.serializeWithDependencies(Task.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.resourceOffer(TaskSetManager.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSchedulerImpl$$resourceOfferSingleTaskSet$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
```

As you can see this cannot be data size issue since the same dataset works fine on local spark with just 4g of executor memory and only using cores of local mac with 16GB memory. While on cluster even where each executor max memory available is 40G, it is still failing with this error.

Please advise what is going wrong here while running this code on YARN cluster.

Comment: Try increasing the value of `spark.driver.memory`, default is 1g. Also set this property in conf files or during submit but not with `SparkConf()`.

Comment: ok. In the spark config code configuration setting the driver memory was set to 15g. But do you think setting it in code doesn't reflect that change?

Comment: Yes. Quoting from docs "In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point."

Comment: ok. So except the driver side settings, we can set other executors and remaining settings through the SparkConf directly right? Only driver side settings should not be set in the SparkConf?

Comment: Yes. Only driver settings.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check this by setting it in conf file.

Comment: Quick question. I am not able to change in conf file maybe because I don't have permission to update it. when I do jupyter notebook in terminal it opens up jupyter. How do I make sure this setting is also passed in terminal when I open up Jupyter ?

Comment: On submitting the job inside jupyter pass it as runtime option `--driver-memory Xg`

Comment: You mean something like this: 

> jupyter notebook --driver-memory 5g

Comment: Provide it to the pyspark job that you run inside jupyter.

Comment: Not sure I understood that. My jupyter is set up with pyspark kernel. So when I just do jupyter notebook in the terminal it opens up the notebook with pyspark kernel

Comment: Oh okay. And how do you run this code inside jupyter?

Comment: You just run it. I have spark installed on the system. In env variables in bash profile I have set the IPYTHON variables with pyspark kernel. So next time when I just type "jupyter notebook" in terminal, it opens up a notebook with pyspark kernel ready and then I can simply run the above codes. Why I am not sure is how to pass the driver memory setting while invoking jupyter in terminal

Comment: Do you have any env variable `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` ? If yes, try adding `--driver-memory=5g` to it

Comment: I have the following in .bashrc. : 

SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark-2.0.2
SPARK_CONF_DIR=/etc/spark-2.0.2/

Are you saying add this to this: 

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS --driver-memory=5g?

Comment: Yes try `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --driver-memory=5g"`. Not sure whether this is syntactically correct.

Comment: As as alternative you can specify memory inside notebook by adding `import os` and `os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master yarn --driver-memory 5g pyspark-shell"` in the first cell.